# Android SDK; computer crash

Tags: android

I'm using Windows 10 64bit.

So I downloaded Android SDK for a project I need to do for college, and when I'm installing everything goes fine, until (what seems to be) the end.

When it's about to finish I get a blue screen saying something like "error occurred, collecting crash info, we will restart the computer for you when finished" or something like that. Below that it says something like "WHEA_UNCORECTABLE_ERROR". Also when it finishes collecting the info (it gets to 100%) it doesn't restart like it says it will, I have to shut down the computer my self and turn it back on.

Does any one know what is going on or how to fix it? I'm kind of screwed if I don't find a solution fast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What "Android SDK" you're referring to exactly? What operating system you're using? What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: does your computer have multiple installations of JDK by any chance? if you can, just uninstall all JDKs and install the newest one for 64-bit before installing the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

-Run the installer with compatibility mode for windows 7/8

-Re-download the SDK to avoid corrupted files in the installer

-Download the Android SDK from another source, or a different version of it.

If nothing works out, it might be a problem with your computer, which would require more research to specify whats the problem. You can try to run the Windows Recovery Tools to try and fix it.